# Wordpress htaccess modrewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess for wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I create a category named "hotels"
I like to change my url via mod rewrite apache module.
My current url like this

```
http://www.mydomains.com/hotels?state=newyork&country=us
```

But I want url like below:

```
http://www.mydomains.com/hotels/us/newyork
```

How can i achieve this?

I tried to get url like this:
`http://www.mydomains.com/hotels/newyork` from `http://www.mydomains.com/hotels?state=newyork`

so i used this line after the rewrite rule but it was not worked.

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]*)$ /hotels/?state=$1 [L]
```

Can some one please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are trying to change permalinks via htaccess? This is more effeciantly done thru the wordpress dashboard under

**Settings> Permalinks**

You can choose a custom permalink structure or choose from the pre selected ones given thru wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Put this before the RewriteConds:

```
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?$ hotels?state=$1
```

You don't want the `[L]` flag because it prevents Wordpress from ever processing it.

Comment: Not working, it shows nothing found. I have put it after RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: No you'll need to put it before the RewriteConds for that RewriteRule.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^hotels/([^/]+)/?$ hotels?state=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress